# How to save SMS to inbox in android?

Tags: android, sms

I have written the below code for sending SMS messages.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(destAddr, null, mMessageText, il, null);
```

But this is not updating in my Inbox, I need to save the same message in Inbox,
Or is there any way to invoke a native SMS application to send SMS ?

Comment: @Lo'oris, @ereOn: Programmatically means that you want do it "through code". It's a perfectly valid word, found in most dictionaries that have been printed in recent years. There are times it's necessary to distinguish between the occasional question we get from a user who is *not* attempting to do something through code. Those questions, of course, belong on Super User instead of here. The problem is that some tasks are much simpler to do and much more commonly done *without* writing a single line of code. The clarifier keeps people from providing those obvious answers.

Answer (score 60):

You can use the sms content provider to read and write sms messages:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", "123456789");
values.put("body", "foo bar");
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

I don't know why you would want to write a message you *send* to the *inbox* but if that is what you want just change the above uri to `"content://sms/inbox"`.

Alternatively you can hand over to a messaging application by starting an activity with an intent similar to the following:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("sms://"));
sendIntent.putExtra("address", "123456789");
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "foo bar");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

**Edit:** However, the `sms://` content provider is not part of the SDK so I strongly recommend *not* using code like this in public applications for [several reasons](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html).

Comment: The SMS content provider is not part of the Android SDK. Your code will break on devices that replace the SMS client with their own. Your code may break in future versions of Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Do you know if this particular problem has an "official" solution ? Dealing with undocumented APIs indeed seems risky, but I couldn't find any other solution so far.

Comment: Sorry to post on such an old question, but is there an alternative to using the sms:// cp?
I am looking for this, but it seems to be the only way to do it.

Comment: I've implemented above mentioned code which will store message into inbox. but somehow I'm unable to find the stored sms. also i'm not even receiving any kind of error/exception. can someone help? thanks in advance

Answer (score 28):

If you want to manually put some SMS to your inbox with a sender name then,

```
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put("address", "+923359110795");//sender name
  values.put("body", "this is my text");
  getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
```

also add these in manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

Now this code will add sms to inbox with a defined sender name, so you can easily handle you problem with this solution,

Comment: Is `READ_SMS` really needed? I would expect only `WRITE_SMS` to be needed.

Comment: @Flow Dear,Use both of them, some times it gives problems, so it will be better if you will write both permissions, otherwise i think it can be done without READ_SMS.

Comment: Edit please my_values to values or conversely

Comment: READ_SMS is needed as well, I also thought that WRITE_SMS would do it but it crashed.

Comment: @sports yes you are right, without WRITE_SMS it might go to create bugs.

Comment: what if the message is more than one message(more than 170 character)

Comment: is it deprecated for android 6 and higher ?

Answer (score 8):

This code will work for all Android versions including above kitkat (19)

```
public boolean saveSms(String phoneNumber, String message, String readState, String time, String folderName) {
        boolean ret = false;
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("address", phoneNumber);
            values.put("body", message);
            values.put("read", readState); //"0" for have not read sms and "1" for have read sms
            values.put("date", time);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                Uri uri = Telephony.Sms.Sent.CONTENT_URI;
                if(folderName.equals("inbox")){
                    uri = Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI;
                }
                mActivity.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
            }
            else {
                mActivity.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + folderName), values);
            }

            ret = true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

**How to call**

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        final String myPackageName = getPackageName();
        if (!Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this).equals(myPackageName)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
            intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, myPackageName);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }else {
            saveSms("111111", "mmmmssssggggg", "0", "", "inbox");
        }
    }else {
        saveSms("111111", "mmmmssssggggg", "0", "", "inbox");
    }
```

**onActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                final String myPackageName = getPackageName();
                if (Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(mActivity).equals(myPackageName)) {

                    //Write to the default sms app
                    saveSms("111111", "mmmmssssggggg", "0", "", "inbox");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more detail or sample app follow link: 
http://wisdomitsol.com/blog/android/sms/how-to-programmatically-save-sms-to-inbox-or-sent-in-android

Comment: There was no "more information" at your link. It was a mere regurgitation of this non-explained answer (which itself seems like a copy of other long-since-posted answers). And yet again, you have included a nondisclosed link to your own site. I've removed the link.

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Content of the SMS goes here...");
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

invoke a native SMS application with content

Comment: whats the difference on using content://sms/ ? I'm interested because I noticed that creating an unread SMS doesn't trigger any native notification. Will this way trigger some notification?

Answer (score -1):

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", phoneNumber);
values.put("body", multimessage);
values.put("read", 1); //"0" for have not read sms and "1" for have read sms
Uri uri = Telephony.Sms.Sent.CONTENT_URI;
Activity ctx = this.cordova.getActivity();
ctx.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```