# Showing Send SMS in the default Message Viewer in android

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have created an app that analyses the SMS that are being received and send messages back to the the Sender.
But those SMS which are being send by my phone automatically are not shown in the default message viewer. How to get it done??

This is the code i use to send SMS

```
package com.lalsoft.janko;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
public String SendMsgBody;


private static final String LOG_TAG = "SMSReactor";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{

    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    String PhNo="";
    String MsgBody="";
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
        {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            PhNo=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            MsgBody=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";
        }


        if(MsgBody.equalsIgnoreCase("Test"))
        {
               SendSMS(PhNo,"Got you!!...Missile Launch initiated.Your location has been traced and the missile will hit your place in approximatly 2 Mins.. ESCAPE!!");
            //SendSMS2(PhNo,"Got you!!...Missile Launch initiated.Your location has been traced and the missile will hit your place in approximatly 2 Mins.. ESCAPE!!");
        }

}



/* public void SendSMS2(String phonenumber,String message)  
{  
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.fromParts(message, phonenumber, null)));  
} 
*/
private void SendSMS(String phonenumber,String message)
{
    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    manager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, null, null);
}

}
```

Here on receiving an SMS with "test" written on it, my application sends the SMS back t o the sender..but in this SendSMS method, its sending the SMS but the send Message is not showing in the native/default SMS Application. What should i do to make this SMS send by my phone back to the Sender being shown in the native SMS application.

Comment: code please. Without code, we can't assume anything.

Comment: this is the code i use to send SMS.. private void SendSMS(String phonenumber,String message)
    {
        SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        manager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, null, null);
    }

Comment: thanks for the links..i was looking for the first method.. But the startactivity is showing errror.."The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type SMSReceiver"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got success..Though i have read in may places this method shouldn't be used in many places.. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642076/how-to-save-sms-to-inbox-in-android) i am using this method here..so if any one is using this code then please be informed about the issues first..

here is my code..

```
 private void SendSMS(Context c,String phonenumber,String message)
{
    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    manager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, null, null);

    //For displaying in Outbox
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("address", phonenumber);
    values.put("body", SendMsgBody);
    c.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
}
```

I am calling this method from this portion( full code shown in the question itself). Additional context is added in my above code..

```
    if(MsgBody.equalsIgnoreCase("Test"))
    {
           SendSMS(context,PhNo,"Got you!!...Missile Launch initiated.Your location has been traced and the missile will hit your place in approximatly 2 Mins.. ESCAPE!!");

    }
```

That's it.. Hope it helps someone else like me..