# Android Write to default SMS App

Tags: android, android-intent

My Android App is using the following code to send an SMS Message:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(smsMessage.getNumber(), null, smsMessage.getText(), sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

However, is it possible to save the outgoing message so that it is displayed in the default SMS app, just as if the user used the default app to send it?

Thanks

Comment: Found the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642076/how-to-save-sms-to-inbox-in-android

Answer (score 2):

you must insert your smsMessage into default  SMS_database
like this

```
public void insertSMS(String address,String body){
private ContentResolver resolver = null;
resolver = context.getContentResolver();//context is your instance of Activity 
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", address);
values.put("body", body);
resolver.insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

}