# With SMS receiver - how can I both abort propagation and still have it saved to content provider?

Tags: android, sms

I'm writing an application that is intercepting some of the SMS mesasges and displays special notifications for them. In this light there is really no need for an additional notification in the status bar or on the screen from the "standard" SMS service. But just to be safe I want the message to not be lost and still show in user's message history.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to guess how you handle your SMS Received Broadcast, but i think you call abortBroadcast(); after you received the sms.
Otherwise the Broadcast would be forwarded to the next receiver, for example the stock sms app.

If you abort the Broadcast with a higher receiver priority, your app will interrupt incoming sms and the stock sms app is not able to save them into the history.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I *want* it to be saved to history, I just don't want any notifications from other apps.

Comment: this post will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746398/android-write-to-default-sms-app