# How can I develop an app that can send a text message?

Tags: android, text, msg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using the native sms app to send an sms without launching itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894120/using-the-native-sms-app-to-send-an-sms-without-launching-itself)

I have noticed many apps have the ability to send a text message to any phone, usually with codes or links or something.

Foursquare for example, when I signed in on my computer it sent me a text on my phone saying "Welcome to Foursquare 'my-name'! Click here to download the app, and have fun exploring! https://foursquare.com/get"

Are there any books or sites (any resources) that can explain to me how to do this? I want to make an app that can send a text message like that. But I have no idea where to even start. I'm a front end developer so I only know easy code like HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP. I have programmed in java before as well, and I'm willing to learn any new programming languages for this.

Thanks!

Comment: text message as in "sms"? or are you talking about emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

The android API documentation is really easy to search..