# How to Import Messages from file to android

Tags: android

I am developing an application which backup the android text Messages, I am able to save the text messages in xml file, Now I want to import this file messages back to android.
I don'nt Know how to do this,
Any help will be most appreciated

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642076/how-to-save-sms-to-inbox-in-android

Answer (score 0):

- To read and parse xml file:

> ```
> XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
>       try {
>           pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
>           XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
>               InputStream in_s = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("temp.xml");
>               parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
>               parser.setInput(in_s, null);
>               parseXML(parser);
>       } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       } catch (IOException e) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
> ```

```
private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
{
ArrayList<SMSMessage> smsMessages = null;
int eventType = parser.getEventType(); SMSMessage smsMessage = null;

while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            String name = null;
            switch (eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    smsMessages = new ArrayList();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    if (name == "message"){
                        smsMessage = new SMSMessage();
                    } else if (smsMessage != null){
                        if (name == "address"){
                            smsMessage.address = parser.nextText();
                        } else if (name == "body"){
                            smsMessage.body = parser.nextText();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("message") && smsMessage != null){
                        smsMessages.add(smsMessage);
                    }
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
}
```

- To write messages to phone memory:

Activity:

```
for(SMSMessage aMessage : smsMessages){
  ContentValues my_values = new ContentValues();
  my_values.put("address", aMessage.address);
  my_values.put("body", aMessage.body);
  getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), my_values);
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

Something like that. Sources: [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/learning-to-parse-xml-data-in-your-android-app/) & [that](http://www.wisdomitsol.com/Blog/Android/Sms/How-to-programmatically-save-sms-to-inbox-or-sent-in-android)

P.S. Haven't compiled myself, mistakes are, obviously, present + SMSMessage class should be implemented, since you haven't told us what this datastructure should contain (how you structure your xml file with all the messages)