# Store the sms broadcast within app to send later

Tags: android, sms

I want to block incoming sms using my app. But, when user disable the blocking, I want all the previously blocked messages to go back to Inbox. I am aborting the sms using abortBroadcast() in smsBroadcastReceiver. How to resend these messages to inbox later? Do I have do something like saving the broadcasts and resend them later?

Comment: Do you just not want the incoming SMS notification to appear, or do you want to keep the messages unavailable (i.e., out of the inbox) until the user unblocks them?

Comment: @MikeM. Exactly the 2nd one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all incoming sms in your own database. After the user is unblocked you can recover the sms as Josef Pfleger wrote in one of [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872131/995926)s:

> You can use the sms content provider to read and write sms messages:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", "123456789");
values.put("body", "foo bar");
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
```

> However, the `sms://` content provider is not part of the SDK so I strongly recommend *not* using code like this in public applications for [several reasons](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html).

It seems to be the most populare way however it is not official.