# android -how to save sent messages sent via SmsMessage

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-sms

I'm using SmsMessage to send sms via my application . this is my code :

```
 SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            sms.sendTextMessage(tel, null, text, null, null);
```

it works fine and I've no problem with sending messages. the only issue is that I want to save sent sms in android message inbox.

How can I do so ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save SMS to inbox in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642076/how-to-save-sms-to-inbox-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sms content provider can help you to write data into message inbox:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("address", tel);
    values.put("body", text);
    values.put("date", "135123000000");
    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

Permission required:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```